# Sending form data and uploading file at the same time in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, multipartform-data

I tried every solution on internet but couldn't get success.

I can upload image files using Angular JS. But this time I need additional values to save the image on server. I am trying to send two arrays. One of them will be the file item, the other one will be a simple post data with folder informations.

```
subjectDetails.addData = function(post_value){
    var defer = $q.defer();

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('files', post_value.files);
    fd.append('data', post_value.data);

    //fd.append("data", 'something');
    //fd.append("data", JSON.stringify(post_value.data));


    $http.post($rootScope.defaultApiPath + '/saveItem', fd, {
        withCredentials : false,
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(response, status){
        defer.resolve(response);
    })
    .error(function(error, status){
        defer.reject(error);
    });


    return defer.promise;
};
```

When I post it, I can get the image file with $_FILES, but $_POST variable is NULL.

I tried

```
var_dump($_POST); //NULL
var_dump($_POST['data']); //NULL
var_dump($_FILES); //shows only the file info. The other array is not in it
```

EDIT

I found the reason. The problem is not in javascript. I use Slim Framework on server side and Slim Framewrok can not parse the FormData Object. When I try to post the FormData object into a simple PHP file, it works. But with Slim Framework 3 it is not working

I tried

```
$request->getBody(); //Still NULL
$request->getParsedBody(); //Still Null
```

Comment: I'm not an angular user. But have you check the angular documentation if they're supporting it?

Comment: I couldn't find anything about sending data and image upload in the angular documantation. But I'm sure that it is sopperted. I just wonder whether this method is supported for old versions of angular. I use 1.5 and it doesn't work. But the posts are from 2015. Not so old :)

Answer (score 0):

You can send multipart form data, This is a great [plugin](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) and look this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SanthoshNelson/ra7czkmh/1/) this can send image and data together to your upload controller. Edit your post and show us what in the server side to help you with

```
 file.upload = Upload.upload({
      url: 'YOUR UPLOAD URL GOES HERE',
      data: {username: $scope.username, file: file},
    });
```

change the server url and look the data, both your from data and file can be send together

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But problem is with slim framework. It can't parse the FormData Object and var_dump($_POST) is still NULL. var_dump($_FILES) returns the file object. But the $_POST is empty